# Missing a property name before the colon (' ') in the (property) (value) declaration in asp.net

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4, lumen

I'm a beginner to asp.net and I tried to use lumen-bootstrap file. Then I got this warning and some buttons don't show

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a false warning because visual studio can not recognize the format of lumen "css" file.

This file will be compiled later to product the final css file.